# Verbtabellen in deutsch und englisch

Tags: german-to-english

ich suche Verbtabellen in deutsch mit englischer Übersetzung.
Alle Verbformen in aktiv und passiv, mit und ohne Modalverb.
(Ich lerne deutsch und englisch).
Ich kann sie leider nirgendwo finden.
Bitte schreibt mir: Wo finde ich solche Tabellen?

Answer (score 3):

Das deutsche Wiktionary hat eine Liste von Verb-Listen: [Wiktionary:Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Verben](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Verben)

Diese Liste enthält 11 Einträge, die jeweils Links zu Listen von Verben sind.
Diese 11 Listen wiederum enthalten einzelne Verben, beispielsweise enthält die Liste der regelmäßigen Verben ca. 3000 Verben.
Jedes einzelne Verb steht als Link in der Liste. Klickt man auf eines der Verben, gelangt man zu der jeweiligen Seite des Verbs. Dort findet man im Abschnitt *Übersetzungen* die Übersetzungen des jeweiligen Verbs in mehreren Sprachen, darunter (fast) immer auch Englisch. Sollte die englische Übersetzung mal fehlen, kann man in https://dict.leo.org/ das Wort eingeben und bekommt dann die englische Übersetzung.

Auf der Wiktionary-Seite eines Verbs steht auf der rechten Seite auch immer eine Tabelle mit den wichtigsten Beugungsformen. Wenn man eine Übersicht über alle Flexionen des Verbs haben will, muss man nur unter dieser Tabelle auf den entsprechenden Link klicken. Aber nicht erschrecken: Es werden dann wirklich ALLE Flexionsformen des Verbs angezeigt, das sind üblicherweise mehr als 100, von denen natürlich viele gleich sind.

Answer (score 0):

There is the book *501 German Verbs* by Henry Strutz. This will do the job for you.

Comment: Do you have an *cutout* or a *screenshot* of this book to see the "Verbtabellen"?

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Sorry, I do not have these.

Comment: @MartinPeters: Warum antwortest du auf English wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde? Die Fragestellerin hat angegeben deutsch und english zu lernen. Du weißt mit Sicherheit, dass ihr Deutsch gut genug ist um die Frage zu stellen. Du weißt aber nicht, ob ihre Englisch besser oder schlechter als ihr Deutsch ist. Daher solltest du dich immer an die Faustregel halten, Antworten immer in jener Sprache zu geben, in der die Frage gestellt wurde.